# Scheduling Actions or Alarms in Android

Tags: android, alarmmanager, alarm, android-alarms, android-jobscheduler

So, I'll start by saying I have already done a lot of research on this, but I'm still stuck.

So here's the goal: Preform a database action (insert a reminder message into local sqlitedb) and send a notification at pre-set times given by some user settings.

And here's the problem: It doesn't work when the app is closed.

I have tried using `AlarmManager` with a broadcast pending intent and with a service pending intent. Neither seemed to work in the problem scenario. After looking into it some more, I found that on newer versions of Android, they are paring back some of the functionality of `AlarmManager` in favor of `JobScheduler`, a new API that 1) seems to be overkill for what I'm doing and 2) won't work on older devices. Sending alarms while the app is closed seems to be one of those "pared-back" features. What should I do? What do I use? What does everyone else usually do? Have I misunderstood something? Please help; I can't find anything on Google!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few methods of running "jobs" pre-lollipop.

You can use the `JobSchedulerCompat` library, but this library has a huge difference compared to the default Lollipop API:

On Lollipop jobs are batched and scheduled for all apps at once. The library however does not have access to other apps data and therefore can't combine jobs from two different apps using the library.

Another option is to use `JobScheduler` for lollipop and greater devices and then use `AlarmManager` for pre-lollipop devices by checking 
`if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP){}`

Finally, you can use the `Sync-Adapter API`.  The Sync adapter encapsulates the code for the tasks that transfer data between the device and a server. Based on the scheduling and triggers you provide in your app, the sync adapter framework runs the code in the sync adapter component. To add a sync adapter component to your app, you need to add the following pieces:

- Sync adapter class.
- Bound Service.
- Sync adapter XML metadata file.
- Declarations in the app manifest.

Comment: I suppose for my case, I'll probably use the version code check. I had seen that around, but it felt like a workaround as opposed to the "right way." I did look at that library, but it looked like it didn't have much activity so I kind of shied away. I think the Sync-Adapter is actually the opposite of what I need, as the whole point of scheduling these reminders is so we don't have to send them from a server. Very helpful reply; thank you!